# Object relationships appear intact for some child objects, non-existent for others

Tags: modeling, transforms, parent

I have an object hierarchy that looks like this:

```
Head
|-> Eyebrow
|-> Nose
|-> Mouth
|-> Eye_Left
|-> Eye_Right
```

Some of the child objects have a relationship line drawn from the center of the object to the origin, while others don't.

Three objects have relationship lines being drawn to the origin:
[image: Three objects have relationship lines being drawn to the origin]

all 'face' objects are children of the head (I'm 'grabbing' the head object and translating it to demonstrate this):
[image: all 'face' objects are children of the head]

What the heck is going on here? I've observed that the objects without relationship lines have the local transform set to (0,0,0), while the objects that do have relationship lines are set to some non-zero translation.  I really want all the objects to behave as the (0,0,0) ones, but I can't figure out what I need to change to get them to behave that way.

I've tried variations of clearing/resetting the parent and it doesn't result in what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out and I feel (kind of) dumb now.

Some objects were positioned in edit mode, while others were positioned in object mode.

The ones that were positioned in edit mode still have their object origin at (0,0,0) with vertices positioned away from the origin.

The ones that were 'misbehaving' were positioned in object mode, and had their origin at some non-zero position.

In both cases, the relationship line was drawn from the origin to the object position, but in the first case, it wasn't visible (since the object position and origin were the same point).